# Npgsql v.2.0.14.3 don't call DbConnection.StateChange event

Tags: c#, npgsql

My project on C# utilize Npgsql library. After updating by NuGet PM from beta version to 2.0.14.3 application has broken: it waits connection state changed event to start the whole work, but DB connection didn't invoke event.

I minimized code to the next chunk:

```
using System;
using Npgsql;
using System.Data;

namespace TestPostgresStateEvent
{
public static class Program
{
    private static NpgsqlConnection connection = null;
    private static System.Timers.Timer checkerTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        connection = new NpgsqlConnection();
        connection.StateChange += OnConnectionStateChanged;
        checkerTimer.Elapsed += (sender, arg) => CheckConnectionState();
        connection.ConnectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=user;Password=qwerty;Database=mydb;";

        connection.Open();
        checkerTimer.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection...");
        Console.ReadLine();

        checkerTimer.Stop();
        connection.Close();
    }

    private static void CheckConnectionState()
    {
        if (connection.FullState == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Checker: Connection established!");
        }
    }

    private static void OnConnectionStateChanged(object sender, StateChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        if (sender == connection)
        {
            if (args.CurrentState == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Event: Connection established!");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And have got the next output:

> Waiting for connection...
>
> Checker: Connection established!
>
> Checker: Connection established!
>
> Checker: Connection established!
>
> ...

So, is this a bug? Is it my fault? I haven't a lot of experience in C#.